# Strange PDO results returning a key for each row value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to get some database results in a very simple application.

Code

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=soundinsider", "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = $pdo->query($sql);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($query->fetchAll());
```

And this is what's output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [username] => simon
        [1] => simon
        [email] => madeup
        [2] => madeup

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [username] => bobwin
        [1] => bobwin
        [email] => fake@email.com
        [2] => fake@email.com

    )

)
```

So there seems to be an extra key created for each result. This wasn't the case when I was coding a month or two ago. Is there something wrong here or is this now PDO behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is configurable behavior:

```
$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

will return associative arrays -- see argument [`$fetch_style`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

you can [configure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) your pdo instance to always do this:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

there also is [`PDOStatement::setFetchMode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) which is useful when using repeated prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

[If you have a look at the manual,](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) you'll see that `fetchAll` defaults to returning both an associate index and a numeric index - I'd suggest you use `fetch` instead and set associate return.